# Indefinite article: Turn traitor vs become a traitor

Tags: grammar, articles

1. The man turned traitor after he was arrested.
2. He became a traitor.

Why is there an "a" in the second sentence but not in the first?

Comment: To *turn traitor* refers to the commission of a treasonous act. To *be a traitor* is the state that follows after the act.

Answer (score 1):

1 The man turned traitor ([dative noun or] adjectival as complement) after he was arrested.

Compare "The man turned *traitorous* ( adjectival as complement) after he was arrested.

OED

> **Traitor**  3. attributive *[noun]* **or as adj.** *That is a traitor, traitorous.*

1837   A. Tennent Vis. Glencoe 18   Some traitor spy, Meant to betray thee with a lie.

OED:

> **Turn** 16.a. intr. To change one's course, so as to go in a different direction; to deviate.

For example: "Meanderings in the West" - Page 62 Elaine Seavey - 2006

> At the town of Wisdom, our road turned west, climbing over St. Joseph Pass

turned west = turned to the west. (NB, here "west" is adverbial)

Comment: What this answer doesn't point out is that this use of _traitor_ is obsolete, except in this one idiom _turn traitor_. You can't say _be/become/seem/appear traitor_, at least, not without being archaic.